# Request Object Properties are null intermittently

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I am at my wits end here! I have an ASP.NET MVC application on a IIS 8 web server in which every thing was working like a champ for 3 months and as of 3 days ago all of a sudden I am getting random Null Reference exceptions when the the code tries to access anything on the Request object.

I mean something as simple as Request.Headers causes an NULL references exception to be thrown. I have checked the request body in the browser and my ops team have sent me logs where the request body looks good.

Has anyone came across something like this before? I mean just all of sudden the request has null properties intermittently. For example sometimes the application loads just find and the user will do something that requires an MVC Action to be invoked where a header is checked or some other request property is accessed and when that happens boom its throws and other times its just fine.

Comment: Are you using HttpContext.Current and async/threading?

Comment: no async or threading just regular old mvc actions being called

Comment: Figured it out, on a whim I checked our appPool Settings. For some strange reason it was set to 18 worker processes when that was changed to 1 the app is working all of a sudden. Not sure how that made the app go bat sh*t crazy but I will take the fix .

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason someone change the AppPool Max worker process to 18 when I changed it back to 1 it all of sudden works like a champ. I Have no idea why 1 worker process works and 18 caused all sorts of crazy to happen.

Comment: Likely this is not a fix but it's hiding most occurrences of the bug. The bug is still there. Using one worker usually is the right choice though so that's an improvement. If you want reliability try to reproduce with 18 workers and find the bug.

Comment: So would the bug be in the code ? I ask because we didn't have an crazy exceptions in the logs until that day where it was changed.  Or would the bug be in server settings somewhere?

Comment: Are you saying there is no bug? Clearly there is, why else would your code crash. Worker processes do not share variables. There was no code/data interaction caused by multiple workers. Likely, the many workers caused higher load and different OS thread scheduled exposing a non-deterministic bug.

Comment: No I was asking? I mean NRE where being thrown every time the Request object was being accessed at any location in the code.